# How to find and print the page titles of HTML links from one URL in Python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing

I'm working on an assignment in which I'm supposed to make a web crawler that reads an input URL, visits each link on the page, and prints the titles of the pages. I don't have a lot of experience with Python, but I had some help, read through a lot of other programs people have written, and currently have this:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import urllib.request

class parseText(HTMLParser):
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    print("Start tag:", tag)
    for attr in attrs:
        print("     attr:", attr)
        if tag == "href" in attrs: 
            print(tag)

pageParse = parseText()

req = urllib.request.Request('http://schoolcraft.edu')

pageRequest = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
pageRequestString = pageRequest.read().decode()
pageParse.feed(pageRequestString)
pageParse.close()
for item in urlText:
    print (item)
```

So I know that it's printing all of the website attributes, instead of just the title, but I'm not sure how to print just the title. Can I still use the HTMLParser module?

Any help is welcome.

EDIT:

I tried the BeautifulSoup code @Padraic posted in python35.exe and I got the following

[Screencap1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnkBf.png)

[Screencap2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcgiZ.png)

I changed `soup = BeautifulSoup( urllib.request.urlopen(base).read())` to `soup = BeautifulSoup( urllib.request.urlopen(base).read(), "html.parser")` and `soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())` to  `soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), "html.parser")`. This caused me to get the same thing, but without the first error telling me to add `"html.parser"`.

Comment: Do you have to use builtin libs? You would also want    `if  "href" in attr:` not `if tag == "href" in attrs`

Comment: My professor didn't say, so I don't think so.

Comment: We can do it with html.parser but it is a lot simpler using bs4

Comment: @R Cate,  you are getting an error relating to ssl, you might be better asking a new question. I have seen this in python2 but not in python3, do you have openssl installed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull all the hrefs and join them to the base url, you can then visit each page and print the title using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def print_titles():
    base = "http://schoolcraft.edu"
    soup = BeautifulSoup( urllib.request.urlopen(base).read())
    for href in (a["href"] for a in soup.select("a[href]")):
        url = urljoin(base, href)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
        title = soup.title
        if title:
            print(title.text.strip())


print_titles()
```

`soup.select("a[href]")` will find all the anchor tags that have href attributes from the first page, then we iterate over each one returned and join it to the base usl with `url = urljoin(base, href)`, we visit each link and print the title text if available.

A sample of the output:

```
Schoolcraft College
Schoolcraft College
Blackboard Learn
Missing cookie
Calendar - Schoolcraft College
A-Z Index - Schoolcraft College
Stay Connected - Schoolcraft College
Schoolcraft College
About Us - Schoolcraft College
Campus Life - Schoolcraft College
Admissions - Schoolcraft College
Resources - Schoolcraft College
Academics - Schoolcraft College
News and Events - Schoolcraft College
```

Using HtmlParser, you will find it easier to parse the links and the title separately, you will also have to handle duplicate links:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib.request


class HrefParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        for _tag, data in attrs:
            if tag == "a" and "href" == _tag:
                url = urljoin('http://schoolcraft.edu', data)
                p = ParseTitle()
                p.feed(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode())
                print(p.title)


class ParseTitle(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = ""
        self.found = None

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "title":
            self.found = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.found and not self.title:
            self.title = data.strip()
            return


pageParse = HrefParser()

pageRequest = urllib.request.urlopen('http://schoolcraft.edu')

pageRequestString = pageRequest.read().decode()
pageParse.feed(pageRequestString)

pageParse.close()
```

Comment: How do I get BeautifulSoup working? I've tried `pip install beautifulsoup4`, but I just get `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\chest\appdata\local\programs\python
\python35\lib\site-packages`. Does that mean I need to upgrade it??

Comment: @RCate,  you cannot import bs4?

Comment: No, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup'` when I try to run the program you posted.

Comment: You are definitely using `python35` to run the code?

Comment: Yes, Python 3.5 64-bit.

Comment: That does not add up, if you are using the correct interpreter you should have no issues. How exactly are you running the code?

Comment: I'm new to Python and my professor has kind of made us figure it out on our own, so there could be something I'm unknowingly doing wrong. But I just open Python 3.5, type `import idlelib.idle` in the console window to open the shell, open the code file from the shell, and press Fn+F5 to run the code.

Comment: Well the first thing I would do it forget about using idle, get a decent ide like pycharm https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/ or at least install ipython. https://ipython.org/.

Comment: For now,  save the script and run it using the full path to the python3.5  interpreter and add what happens.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by running it "using the full path to the python 3.5 interpreter"?

Comment: I mean tthe full path to the python interpreter  /users/...../python35.exe, I added another example of how to do it using just the HtmlParser